# Notification size

Tags: java, android, notifications

There is a possibility to set size of notification (I don't want a solution with click and slide down to see a bigger picture).
I create a code with custom layout, and when on my mobile phone I turned on my application, notification is showed up when I enlarged I saw my wallpaper for this notification, but I want sth like this :
[image]

without enlarging notification, I want a static big notification with wallpaper, that's possible ?

My code :

```
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MyActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.awesome_big_beast_notification);
        expandedView.setTextViewText(R.id.text1, "TEST NOTIFY");
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        //we have a cute kitten for a background and also we can display image in right corner
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher),
                30, 30, true);
        expandedView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image1, result); //in here we can set the size :)
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getResources(), R.drawable.meow))
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                .setContentTitle("Don't touch me")
                .setStyle(new Notification.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                        getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher),
                                200, 200, true)))
                .build();
        notification.bigContentView = expandedView;

        ((NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
                .notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: pls edit your question to point out the question

Comment: so..you want one wallpaper which appears as a background for all notifications from your app?

Comment: Yes :) with height from range 100-240dp

Comment: i doubt if that can be done considering it will also require grouping your notifications together(like..if there is one external notification between 2 from your app), considering we handle the wallpaper part smartly choosing some pattern which would make it look as one

Comment: So there is no other solution? Only grouping ?

Comment: can't think of anything for now, will leave a comment if i find something